# Why must the constexpr specifier be explicitly specified for functions?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

In C++, the `constexpr` specifier must be specified by the programmer on a constexpr function.  The compiler is not allowed to infer the constexpr-ness of a function.

Yet, the standard allows a function to be marked as `constexpr` as long as there exists one set of argument values such that the function can be evaluated at compile time.

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int constexpr_stuff() { return 1 + 2 * 3 + 4; }
int non_constexpr_stuff() {
    int tmp =0;
    std::cin >> tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int f() {
    return constexpr_stuff();
}

constexpr int g(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return constexpr_stuff();
    else return non_constexpr_stuff();
}

// constexpr int k1 = f(); // compile error
constexpr int k2 = g(0); // ok
// constexpr int k3 = g(1); // compile error
```

`f` is a non-constexpr function, so it is a compile error to assign its result to a constexpr variable.  However, `g` is conditionally constexpr, and the compiler is clearly capable of inferring that `g(0)` is constexpr.

Is there any technical reason why the standard does not allow the compiler to infer the constexpr-ness of a function?